# App always crashes when calling onClickListerner()

Tags: android

App always crashes when calling saveDetails() function. Don't know what is the main reason. I couldn't figure out. Someone, please help me.

When I remove saveDetails() function the app launches perfectly and calls contact_details layout also when imageButton is clicked. But when the function is added the app just crashes. The log shows error on saveButton.setOnClickListener().

```
package com.bikram.contacts;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    EditText firstName, lastName, phoneNumber;
    ImageButton imageButton;
    Button saveButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.first_name);
        lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.last_name);
        phoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);

        viewName();
        addContacts();
        saveDetails();

    }

    public void saveDetails() {
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void addContacts() {
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.contact_details);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void viewName() {
        Cursor result = databaseHelper.getName();
        ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
        while (result.moveToNext()) {
            arrayList.add(result.getString(0));
            arrayList.add(result.getString(1));
        }
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.text_view, arrayList);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.display_full_name);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.bikram.contacts;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Sabina on 13-Nov-16.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String databaseName = "Contact.db";
    public static final String tableName = "contact_details";
    public static final String col_1 = "First Name";
    public static final String col_2 = "Last Name";
    public static final String col_3 = "Mobile Number";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("Create table " + tableName + "(First Name Text, Last Name Text, Mobile Number Number Not Null Primary Key);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists" + tableName);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor getName() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "Select First Name, Last Name from " + tableName;
        Cursor result = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return result;
    }

    public boolean addContactDetails(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(col_1, firstName);
        contentValues.put(col_2, lastName);
        contentValues.put(col_3, phoneNumber);

        long result = db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

Log from android Monitor

```
11-13 18:27:49.343 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fd7ce0)
11-13 18:27:49.343 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
11-13 18:27:49.344 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bikram.contacts/com.bikram.contacts.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 18:27:49.345 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2347)
11-13 18:27:49.345 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2399)
11-13 18:27:49.345 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:160)
11-13 18:27:49.345 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
11-13 18:27:49.346 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
11-13 18:27:49.346 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
11-13 18:27:49.346 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
11-13 18:27:49.346 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 18:27:49.346 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-13 18:27:49.346 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
11-13 18:27:49.347 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
11-13 18:27:49.347 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 18:27:49.347 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-13 18:27:49.348 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at com.bikram.contacts.MainActivity.saveDetails(MainActivity.java:44)
11-13 18:27:49.348 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at com.bikram.contacts.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
11-13 18:27:49.348 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
11-13 18:27:49.348 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
11-13 18:27:49.348 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
11-13 18:27:49.348 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/System.err:  ... 11 more
11-13 18:27:49.348 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
11-13 18:27:49.350 2108-2108/com.bikram.contacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.bikram.contacts, PID: 2108
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bikram.contacts/com.bikram.contacts.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2347)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2399)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:160)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                       at com.bikram.contacts.MainActivity.saveDetails(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                       at com.bikram.contacts.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2399) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:160) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5330) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645) 
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5: SuspendAll starting
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=1 status=7 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=11 status=7 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=10 status=7 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=9 status=7 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=8 status=4 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=7 status=4 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=6 status=4 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=4 status=8 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=3 status=8 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5:   threadid=2 status=8 sc=1 dc=0
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5: SuspendAll complete : 1
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5: ResumeAll starting
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5: ResumeAll waking others
11-13 18:27:54.661 2108-2116/com.bikram.contacts D/dalvikvm: threadid=5: ResumeAll complete
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/display_full_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/add_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

contact_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Contact" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/last_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:text="Save" />
</LinearLayout>
```

text_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id = "@+id/textView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post logcat and xml

Comment: post your layout also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include contact_details in your activity_main.xml. The reason has already been explained by @clownba0t above.

Comment: I just want to make multiple layout for multiple inputs. If i include contact_details into activity _main then i i will have one layout only.

Comment: That could work, although I think the layout and code would become more complex as a result. The contact details layout looks to only be displayed after a button is clicked, so you'd need to have it in a container layout with initial visibility "gone". You'd also need to move the existing content of `activity_main` into a sibling container layout with initial visibility "visible". Then, you'd set the visibility of each container appropriately based on the various button clicks. A bit complex for my tastes - I'd still prefer the separate activity/fragments approach.

Comment: Use a linear layout then. You can add views to it at runtime according to your requirement. Here you cant do findViewById , if the same layout is not there in your main layout that you set in setContentView of the activity.

Comment: I am new to android. Can you give some example to acheive this by linear layout.

Comment: I will surely help u out with the code. Please provide some UI Wireframes of what your screen should look like so that I can guide you accordingly.

Comment: I just want to have a add button on main screen which will redirect to new layout screen. The new layout screen will have some fields to put in database. It contains a save button to save in database.

Comment: Then you need two activities with individual layout.xml and class.java. The first screen will intent you to second screen. Make sure the screens in which you define your UI components will have their wiring in their respective java file.

Comment: I made a new java class for contacts_details layout and called the button and it worked fine. Thank you  for your help. I will post more question if i get stuck anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use two layouts in the same activity. `activity_main.xml` is loaded in `onCreate`, but it doesn't contain a `Button` with id `save_button`. So when you call `saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);`, `saveButton` ends up with a value of `null`.

Later, in `addContacts`, you set up to change the content view of the activity to `contact_details` upon the click of a button. This layout does include a `Button` with id `save_button`, but you don't call `findViewById` again and so the `saveButton` variable remains `null`. Even if you did, the issue would still manifest because the crash happens before the button could ever be clicked.

The reason you're seeing a crash is because after calling `addContacts` you go on to call the `saveDetails` method, which attempts to call a method on the `saveButton` variable. As explained above that variable contains `null`, hence the NPE and crash.

I'd recommend not using multiple content views in a single activity. Consider creating a new activity to handle the contact details entry, and start that when the add button is pressed. If you don't want to use an activity for this you could just as easily use fragments instead.